# How can I use a generic-type constraint extension for a class with a `Codable` type constraint?

Tags: swift

Say my class definition is:

```
class Foo<T: Codable> {
    let bar: T
}
```

I want to extend arrays of this type:

```
extension Array where Element: Foo<Codable> { /* do something based on `bar` values */ }
```

This produces the error

> Protocol 'Codable' (aka 'Decodable & Encodable') as a type cannot conform to 'Decodable'

I did read in another question that conforming `T` to `Encodable`/`Decodable` isn't possible if `T == Encodable/Decodable` since a protocol can't conform to itself, but this is only for a certain property so I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think is better to use protocol instead class like this.

```
protocol FooProtocol {
    associatedtype T : Codable
    var bar: T {get set}
}

extension Array  where Element: FooProtocol {
        
}
```

Comment: this doesnt require that bar conforms to Codable. What OP needs is `associatedtype T: Codable` and no constraint to the protocol itself

Comment: yes you are rigth, that was my mistake.